# Associated types to normalize serializable data via traits and a generic type

Tags: compiler-errors, scope, rust, traits

I tried to implement a type that would "enforce" some schema to my responses in [Tide](https://github.com/rustasync/tide) but keep getting the "Items from traits can only be used..." compiler error.

```
#![feature(async_await, futures_api, await_macro, arbitrary_self_types)]
#![allow(proc_macro_derive_resolution_fallback)]

use serde_derive::Serialize;
use tide::{body::Json, IntoResponse, Response};

#[derive(Serialize)]
struct Document<Attrs, Rels> {
    data: PrimaryData<Attrs, Rels>,
}

#[derive(Serialize)]
struct PrimaryData<Attrs, Rels> {
    id: i32,
    kind: String,
    attributes: Attrs,
    relationships: Rels,
}

trait IntoPrimaryData: Send {
    type Attrs: serde::Serialize;
    type Rels: serde::Serialize;

    fn into_primary_data(self) -> PrimaryData<Self::Attrs, Self::Rels>;
}

struct ServiceResponse<T: IntoPrimaryData>(T);

impl<T: IntoPrimaryData> IntoResponse for ServiceResponse<T> {
    fn into_response(self) -> Response {
        Json(Document {
            data: self.0.into_primary_data(),
        })
        .with_status(http::status::StatusCode::OK)
        .into_response()
    }
}

#[derive(Serialize)]
struct User {
    id: i32,
    primary_email: String,
}

#[derive(Serialize)]
struct UserAttrs {
    primary_email: String,
}

impl IntoPrimaryData for User {
    type Attrs = UserAttrs;
    type Rels = ();

    fn into_primary_data(self) -> PrimaryData<Self::Attrs, Self::Rels> {
        PrimaryData {
            id: self.id,
            kind: "user".into(),
            attributes: UserAttrs {
                primary_email: self.primary_email,
            },
            relationships: (),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

```
[dependencies]
tide = "0.0.5"
http = "0.1.16"
serde = "1.0.89"
serde_derive = "1.0.89"
```

The compiler returns the error

```
error[E0599]: no method named `with_status` found for type `tide::body::Json<Document<<T as IntoPrimaryData>::Attrs, <T as IntoPrimaryData>::Rels>>` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:34:10
   |
34 |         .with_status(http::status::StatusCode::OK)
   |          ^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: the method `with_status` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
           `tide::body::Json<Document<<T as IntoPrimaryData>::Attrs, <T as IntoPrimaryData>::Rels>> : tide::response::IntoResponse`
   = help: items from traits can only be used if the trait is implemented and in scope
   = note: the following trait defines an item `with_status`, perhaps you need to implement it:
           candidate #1: `tide::response::IntoResponse`
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error but I feel like it has something to do with the line `data: self.0.into_primary_data()` not being "specific" enough and that it is not known what the types of `Self::Attrs` and `Self::Rels` are. However, I know that I also get this same error (minus the help tip about "items from traits can only be...") if one of the nested types don't implement `serde::Serialize` but from what I can tell, I've added those bounds everywhere they need to be.

I've tried doing this in what feels like a million ways now and can't quite seem to come up with a way to get some normalized structure for my responses.

I'm using `rustc 1.34.0-nightly (02c4c2892 2019-02-26)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't correctly specified the complete bounds on your associated types.

[`Json`](https://docs.rs/tide/0.0.5/tide/body/struct.Json.html) only implements `IntoResponse` when the type it contains implements both `Send` and `Serialize`:

```
impl<T: Send + Serialize> IntoResponse for Json<T>
```

You need to include `Send` in the bounds for the associated types:

```
trait IntoPrimaryData: Send {
    type Attrs: serde::Serialize + Send;
    //                           ^^^^^^
    type Rels: serde::Serialize + Send;
    //                          ^^^^^^

    fn into_primary_data(self) -> PrimaryData<Self::Attrs, Self::Rels>;
}
```

#### Debugging steps

This line of the error message seemed promising:

```
the method `with_status` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
`tide::body::Json<Document<<T as IntoPrimaryData>::Attrs, <T as IntoPrimaryData>::Rels>> : tide::response::IntoResponse`
```

This states that we could call `with_status` except that the compiler didn't know that the type implemented the trait. From there, I went to the documentation of [`Json`](https://docs.rs/tide/0.0.5/tide/body/struct.Json.html) to see if it implemented `IntoRespose` and if so, under what conditions:

```
impl<T: Send + Serialize> IntoResponse for Json<T>
```

Based on that, we know that this `T` must be `PrimaryData<T::Attrs, T::Rels>` and it must implement `Send + Serialize`.

We see that `PrimaryData` derives `Serialize`:

```
#[derive(Serialize)]
struct PrimaryData<Attrs, Rels> {
```

By existing knowledge, I know that most `derive`d traits require that all of the generic types also implement the trait. It's less obvious, but the same is true for [`Send`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Send.html).

From there, it's a matter of proving that the specific types for `Attrs` and `Rels` implement `Serialize` and `Send`. The associated type bounds handled one but not the other.

Deciding where to place the bounds is a matter of intent and style — they could go on the function, the `impl` block, or in the trait. Since the trait already had mention of `Serialize`, it seemed a natural place to add the additional bound.

I also made one large misstep — I assumed that you had correctly specified the bounds and were running into [a compiler limitation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44790642/155423) ([also](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37600687/155423)). Only when I tried to apply the suggested duplicate did I realize that the bounds were incorrect.

See also:

- [Deriving a trait results in unexpected compiler error, but the manual implementation works](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39415052/155423)
- [`Send`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Send.html)

Comment: Do you mind me asking the steps you took to figure that out? I wasn't sure what steps I should've taken when I ran into the issue in order to figure out what the cause was. Is it just a matter of experience/feeling or did you take some explicit steps to figure it out? Out of curiosity

Comment: @PeteJodo added.